# Do endocrine cells always lie adjacent to capillaries?

Tags: physiology, anatomy

The circulatory system transports plasma contents to the body via the interstitial circulatory system, reabsorbed with the lymphatic system. Cell metabolism "waste products" are transported into the blood via this "sewer system", to for example be excreted by the urinary system. The lymphatic system provides a basic route for interstitial fluid to return into the blood stream. The endocrine system has to be relatively fast, and, lymphatic transportation is relatively slow. Do endocrine cells always lie adjacent to capillaries so that hormones are secreted directly into the blood stream?